# Subtracting the character before when it finds a specific letter

Tags: java

```
         String secondLine = "...E......E..E.E";
```

The secondLine is in a txt file and therefore the E can be anywhere just after a dot depending on the number failed.

in total there is meant to be just 12 of these but java adds an E after the dot before to indicate that test was failed. I am a novice programmer and would like a loop that would go through that string to take off the dot before every E so I can integrate into my main application. The resulting output should look like this ..E.....E.EE  Thank you in advance

Comment: more info please, your question isn't clear enough.

Comment: We don't write code because we're bored*; show the code you've tried and which is failing to remove the . before the E and what the problem is. (Edit: Ok, some people do)

Comment: @Poldie - *We don't write code because we're bored* - some of us do :P

Comment: @TheLostMind I have taken off the single quotes sorry

Comment: @RoeyGolzarpoor I have added more info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using String's [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) method like below:

```
String secondLine = "...E......E..E.E";
System.out.println(secondLine.replace(".E", "E"));
Output:
..E.....E.EE
```

Comment: You are a star :)) cant believe it was just a line of code. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Use regex like this :

```
public static void main(String... strings) {
    String secondLine = "...E......E..E.E";
    System.out.println(secondLine.replaceAll("\\.E", "E"));
}
```

O/P:

```
..E.....E.EE
```